# Reactive Cocoa diferences between KVC and instance object

Tags: ios, key-value-observing, reactive-cocoa, key-value-coding, kvc

I use this code to subscribe events with my mutable array:

```
[RACObserve(self, marray) subscribeNext:^....
```

I am new in RAC and I don't understand why for example if I use:

```
NSMutableArray *keyValueCodingArray = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"marray"];

[keyValueCodingArray addObject:@"string"];
```

everything works ok and if I add something to my `keyValueCodingArray` which is my `marray` it reacts on events and if I remove some object from keyValueCodingArray it also react.

But if use the instance directly the RACObserve block wont work. I mean seems like it does not observe any changes with array:

```
[self.marray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

What is the differences?

Comment: oh I just print out array, it has NSKeyValueNotifyingMutableArray, seems I think I need to read more deeper into KVC =)

Comment: NS[Mutable]Array doesn't implement the [accessor methods for to-many properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-178830-BAJEDEFB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is the following:

```
[[keyValueCodingArray rac_signalForSelector:@selector(addObject:)] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    <#code#>
}];
```

and

```
[[keyValueCodingArray rac_signalForSelector:@selector(removeObject:)] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    <#code#>
}];
```

Your code only checks the changes on the array property, not calls to it's value.

Comment: I meant the problem was in the understanding, so if I use `[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"marray"];` it works, but if I use direct `self.marray` as reference and try to invoke `-addObject:` method it wont work I mean we never get call `[RACObserve(self, marray) subscribeNext:^`, because of using direct reference.

Comment: I have not tested you code, but why when we use instance we don't receive any updates?

Comment: I think because keyvaluecodingarray is a different instance of what you're trying to observe. with racobserve you're observing for specific instances